# CSS Hiding Dropdown Menu for Specific Menu Items

Tags: html, css, confluence

I have the following menu implemented on a HTML/CSS theme running on Confluence.

[image]

The theme that I'm running provides options to activate drop-down menu's for all menu items by default. However, I'd like the dropdown menu to be displayed for only one of the menu items.

The theme doesn't provide the option to toggle dropdowns for specific menu items, which is why I'm forced to resort to custom CSS.

The HTML corresponding to the RELEASE NOTES menu item is as so --

```html
<li id="rw_category_key_notes" data-name-key="notes">

<a class="rw_custom_url" href="http://localhost:8090/display/DDB/Release+Notes">

<span class="rw_item_name">RELEASE NOTES</span>
<span class="rw_item_dd rw_dropdown_btn"></span>

</a>

</li>
```

Also, adding the following custom CSS removes the dropdown menu for ALL menu items.

```css
#rw_category_menu.rw_theme_underline ul.rw_category_items li a .rw_item_dd{
display: none;
}
```

I'd like CSS to conditionally not display the dropdown for the RELEASE NOTES menu item, displaying it only for LEARNING instead.

How would I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use an id or a specific class to target only that element and show your dropdown accordingly ?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would be the way but my CSS know-how is minuscule and I'm not quite sure of the syntax to target specific elements.

Made a few attempts but they didn't quite work.

Comment: Most CMS and themes use a menu that triggers dropdown only if your menu has children, is it not the case for you ?

Comment: @Jake, no that is not an option here. I've asked the theme creators as well and they agree its a fault; which is why I'm trying to find a custom CSS solution.

Comment: Are you trying to only remove the dropdown button, or what?

Comment: @misorude, yes only the dropdown.

Comment: If you only want to hide that arrow, then something like `#rw_category_key_notes .rw_dropdown_btn { display: none; }` should do. (If a rule with higher specificity interferes, add `!important`)

Comment: @misorude That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target only the first instance of element you can use

```
ul.your-ul-class > li {
  // target only the 1st node instance
}

ul.your-ul-class li > li.second-intance {
  // target only the 2nd node instance
}
```

this will only the first instance of the node

```
ex:
<ul>
  <li> -- CSS implemented -- <li>
  <li> -- CSS implemented --
    <ul>
      <li class="second-intance" > -- NO CSS implemented -- </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @misorude!

That solved it, I applied --

```css
#rw_category_key_notes .rw_dropdown_btn { display: none; }
```

to the theme's custom CSS as you suggested. By itself it doesn't hide the dropdown menu for the RELEASE NOTES menu item, but adding !important at the end makes it work.

```css
#rw_category_key_notes .rw_dropdown_btn { display: none !important; }
```